# NSImage from Texture Atlas

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nstableview, nsimage, sprite-sheet

I want to build a LevelEditor and would need the sprites (their images) stored in a Texture Atlas of cocos2d in a NSTableView. Any idea how one could approach that?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by creating a CCSprite for each image in your texture atlas and then rendering them into a CCRenderTexture. CCRenderTexture has the ability to save its texture as a NSImage.

More info on how to do this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/27769

Comment: There is nothing referring to how to save an NSImage from a CCRenderTexture on the page you link to.